# How do I prevent a click on an element in a SelectableList from triggering onChange?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

So basically, I have a checkbox that triggers one event and a SelectableList that triggers another event onChange. The problem is that I thought the events were getting triggered by the click of each element in the List, but it wasn't the case and it was triggered by the onChange on SelectableList, how do I make sure that the onCheck event doesn't trigger the onChange on SelectableList?

I put an e.stopPropagation inside handleOnCheckItem, which handles the onCheck event, but because the function doesn't prevent onChange, it won't really work. Is there a way to prevent the onChange on the parent component?

```
<SelectableList value={this.state.selectedIndex} onChange={this.requestChange.bind(this)}>
    <ListItem value={1} primaryText="Menu1" 
      primaryText={
        <div>
          <Checkbox
            key={id}
            checked={
              selectedItems.filter(item => item.id == id)
                .length !== 0
                ? true
                : false
            }
            style={styles.checkbox}
            onCheck={onCheckItem.bind(this, id)}
          />
          {name}
          <span style={styles.span}>{created}</span>
        </div>
      }leftAvatar={<Avatar src="img1.png" />}/>
    <ListItem value={2} primaryText="Menu2"
      primaryText={
        <div>
          <Checkbox
            key={id}
            checked={
              selectedItems.filter(item => item.id == id)
                .length !== 0
                ? true
                : false
            }
            style={styles.checkbox}
            onCheck={onCheckItem.bind(this, id)}
          />
          {name}
          <span style={styles.span}>{created}</span>
        </div>
      }leftAvatar={<Avatar src="img1.png" />}/> leftAvatar={<Avatar src="img2.png" />}/>
  </SelectableList>
```

The class containing the event handler:

```
class ItemsContainer extends Component {
...

  handleOnCheckItem = (id, e) => {
    console.log('e');
    console.log(typeof e);
    console.log(e);
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.props.changeSelectedItems(id)
  }
}
```

I would like the onChange event to not be triggered whenever I check a ListItem. By the way, I am using v0 of material-ui.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use `onCheck` instead of `onChange` for the `ListItem`'s event handler?

Comment: I need to use both onChange and onCheck. Also, onChange is on the parent's component of the listitems.